# Insert multiple record into database using for loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a form which inserts multiple records.

The form has a: field user name(A), BTR(B), Facility used(C), number Of Sample (D), and record related to different sample (1,2,3..).

Using this form I am inserting the multiple record (ABCD1, ABCD2, ABCD3, ABCD4...  into the database.

I tried using the for loop but it is saving the last record value. I am  not able to do it please help me.

```
 if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $btr=$_POST['btr'];
    $facility=$_POST['facility'];
    $type=$_POST['type'];
    $samplelocation=$_POST['samplelocation'];
    $remarks=$_POST['remarks'];
    $samplecount=$_POST['samplecount'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO  tblfacility(user,btr,facility,type,samplelocation,remarks) VALUES(:user,:btr,:facility,:type,:samplelocation,:remarks)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':user',$user,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':btr',$btr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':facility',$facility,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':type',$type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':samplelocation',$samplelocation,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':remarks',$remarks,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    if($lastInsertId)
    {
    $_SESSION['msg']="Sample Listed successfully";
    header('location:manage-books.php');
    }
    else 
    {
    $_SESSION['error']="Something went wrong. Please try again";
    header('location:manage-books.php');
    <label>BTR No.<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="btr"  required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <label>BTR No.<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="btr"  required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Facility Used<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" type="text" name="facility"  required="required" autocomplete="off"  />
      <option value="AMS">AMS 14C</option>
      <option value="AMS">AMS 10Be</option>
      </select>  
    <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Number Of Sample<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="samplecount" onchange="samplecount()"  required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <td>

    <table   class="table table-striped small-text" id="tb" >
    <tr class="tr-header">
    <h4 style="color:darkGreen;" ><b><u>SAMPLE INFORMATION</u></b></h4> 
    <th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
    <th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">TYPE OF SAMPLE</th>
    <th  class= "col-md-2" align="centre">Sample Location</th>
    <th class= "col-md-6" align="centre"> Remarks</th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Sample"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text"  name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
    <td><select  type="text" name="type" class="form-control">
      <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
       <option value="BONE">BONE</option>
       <option value="CARBONATE">CARBONATE</option>
      </select></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="samplelocation" class="form-control" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="remarks" class="form-control"></td>

    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
    <?php }?>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-info"  align="middle" >ADD </button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
                  var data = $("#tb tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb");
                  data.find("input").val('');

         });
         $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
             var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
                if(trIndex>1) {
                 $(this).closest("tr").remove();
               } else {
                 alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
               }
          });
    }); 

    </script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see any `<form>` tags around your inputs, are you getting around those somehow with JS code? Your `samplelocation` and `remarks` inputs also seem to be arrays, but you don't split them when they are submitted. I'm not sure whether that is necessary if you only submit one at a time.

Comment: @droopsnoot that may be syntax error, as far as  form is concerned it is fine the problem is only with the saving the mulyiple row .

Comment: You also have the `btr` field twice. Is there something mixed up in the post?

Comment: ya it was mistake about btr

Comment: Perhaps you could post the corrected code.

Comment: can  i post the code again  here ?

Comment: You can edit your post for a certain amount of time. Not sure how long, though. If you still have an "edit" link at the bottom, try it.

Comment: The only "for loop" I can see here is `for($i=1;$i<=1;$i++)`, and if you examine the values you have put into it, you can see that it will only execute once. It's also nowhere near the code that actually writes into the database, it's in the display code. I still don't see an opening `<form>` tag, to see how you submit the form to the PHP code. I can see a closing one. And if you change the loop to execute more than once, you'll end up with multiple input fields of the same name, which will confuse matters further.

Comment: Is there code missing from the post? It seems that you open a curly-brace when you check if the "add" element exists, but I can't see where you close it. You also open a pair around the "else" clause after you've checked whether the data inserted, but don't close it. That's also not a good way to check if the record inserted - check the return from `execute()` instead. Also, you should `exit()` after doing a header relocate.

Comment: I think you need to add some debugging, you can `var_dump()` or `echo` various values as they come from your form. There's not enough here for me to actually try the code locally, too many `div`s that close before they're opened, PHP clauses that open but never close, it's really difficult to figure out which bits you've edited down for the post that might affect how it works.

Comment: still not able to get any help

Comment: It's hard to know what more to suggest, other than to first address the various errors in the code that I pointed out. I can't offer any more help unless you can do that, and also answer some of the questions I've asked.

Answer (score 0):

add `[]` in all your input names eg: `name="user[]"`. this will give you a array of your input element after you submit.

so in your `if(isset($_POST['add']))` you can get this array like `$arr_user = $_POST['user'];` then use a for loop to loop these data. 
Your tr tag could be like,

```
<tr class="tr-header">
<h4 style="color:darkGreen;" ><b><u>SAMPLE INFORMATION</u></b></h4> 
<th class= "col-md-1" align="centre">Sl.No.</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">TYPE OF SAMPLE</th>
<th  class= "col-md-2" align="centre">Sample Location</th>
<th class= "col-md-6" align="centre"> Remarks</th>
<th><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore" title="Add More Sample"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>

<tr>
<td><input type="text"  name="slno[]" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><select  type="text" name="type[]" class="form-control">
  <option value="SELECT TYPE">SELECT TYPE</option>
   <option value="BONE">BONE</option>
   <option value="CARBONATE">CARBONATE</option>
  </select></td>

<td><input type="text" name="samplelocation[]" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="remarks[]" class="form-control"></td>

<td><a href='javascript:void(0);'  class='remove'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
<?php }?>
</tr>
```